# How to use django-filter with django-tables2

Tags: django, django-filter, django-tables2

I'm trying to add a filter feature in my `django-tables 2` so I opted for `django-filter`. I followed the documentation it worked great but I don't know how to integrate it with `django-tables 2`. 
I made a filter class and in the view i made something like this :

```
queryset = Fitzroyfalls.objects.select_related().all()
f = FitzroyfallsFilter(request.GET, queryset=queryset)
table = FitsroyFallsTable(f.queryset)
table.paginate(page=request.GET.get('page', 1), per_page=25)
RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
return render(request, 'query.html', {'table': table})
```

but nothing happens, it only displays the table with all data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of trying, I got the solution which is simple.
In the view add those lines :

```
if request.method == "GET"
    list1=list()
    for obj in f:
        list1.append(obj)
    table=FitsroyFallsTable(list1)
```

aaand that's it !

Answer (score 3):

I checked out the `__iter__` method for the `FilterSet` and it basically accesses the `property` `qs`. So @huiming's answer works for me. I adapted your code as follows:

```
queryset = Fitzroyfalls.objects.select_related().all()
f = FitzroyfallsFilter(request.GET, queryset=queryset)
table = FitsroyFallsTable(f.qs)
RequestConfig(request, paginate={"per_page": 25, "page": 1}).configure(table)
return render(request, 'query.html', {'table': table, 'filter': f})
```

I'm using:

```
django-filter==0.7
django-tables2==0.14.0
Django==1.6
```

Answer (score 1):

table = FitsroyFallsTable(f.qs)

Comment: Can you add some detail?

Answer (score -1):

For **CBV**:

```
class FilteredSingleTableView(FilterView, SingleTableView):

    def get_table_data(self):
        data = super(FilteredSingleTableView, self).get_table_data()
        return data if self.object_list is None else self.object_list
```

Usage:

```
class UserList(FilteredSingleTableView):
    template_name = 'accounts/users_list.html'
    model = User
    table_class = UserTable
    paginate_by = 10
    filterset_class = UserFilter
```